# How one can show that this polynomial is negative

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How one can show that this polynomial.

$$-2+2x^{2k+1}-x^{3k+2}+x^{k-1}$$

is negative for all integer $k>1$ and real $x>2$.

I have no idea to start.

Comment: @greedoid: No it is $k-1$.

Comment: Any reason why it should be $x>5$ specifically? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/esk3my2jfc

Comment: That will likely become clear in the answer

Comment: @HackerBoss I only meant that because it seems that for $k>1,$ $-2+2x^{2k+1}-x^{3k+2}+x^{k-1}$ is negative for all values $x>1.18.$

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan: How you get this result

Comment: The desmos link in my first comment

Comment: Just for confirmation: is it $-2+2x^{2k+1}-x^{3k+2}+x^{k-1}$ or $-2+(2x)^{2k+1}-x^{3k+2}+x^{k-1}$?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan: The first expression

Comment: I must say that I'm rather confused that a question from such an experienced user that has *literally* no context got so many upvotes and ended up on HNQ....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $x>2$ we have $x^{k+1} >4x^{k-1}>x^{k-1}$

so we have:

$$x^{2k+1}(2-x^{k+1})-(2-x^{k-1})<x^{2k+1}(2-x^{k-1})-(2-x^{k-1})= \underbrace{(x^{2k+1}-1)}_{>0}\underbrace{(2-x^{k-1})}_{<0}$$

Answer (score 4):

Well I can change all the signs and assert that the result is positive. If I multiply by $x$ I don't change the sign, because $x$ is positive and I then put $y=x^k$ to simplify the expression. Then I am looking at $$x^3y^3-2x^2y^2-y+2\gt 0$$

I am then guessing that $-2$ is irrelevant once $x$ and $k$ are large, so I drop it and divide through by $y$ (positive) and I expect to find $$x^3y^2-2x^2y-1\gt 0$$ perhaps with some extra cases to consider. Now I drop the $-1$ as small in relation to the other terms and divide through by $x^2y$ (positive) and consider $$xy-2$$

Now with $k\gt 1$ and $x\gt 5$ we have also $y\gt 5$ so that $$xy-2\gt23$$

Now we see how to reverse the process with crude estimates.

Multiply through by $x^2y^\gt 1$ (very crude estimate) and subtract $1$ to obtain $$x^3y^2-2x^2y-1\gt 23x^2y-1\gt 22$$

Multiply by $y\gt 1$and add $2$ to obtain $$x^3y^3-2x^2y^2-y+2\gt22y+2\gt 24\gt 0$$

which is equivalent to the original inequality. As you see, only very crude estimates are required. I used $y$ to see if there were any obvious squares hiding in he background.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$-2+2x^{2k+1}-x^{3k+2}+x^{k-1}=-2+\left(2x^{k+2}-x^{2k+3}+1\right)x^{k-1}$$
and
$$2x^{k+2}-x^{2k+3}+1=1+\left(2-x^{k+1}\right)x^{k+2}$$
If $x > 5$, and $k>1$, then $2-x^{k+1}<-1$, $x^{k+2}>1$, and $x^{k-1}>1$, so that $$-2+\left(1+\left(2-x^{k+1}\right)x^{k+2}\right)x^{k-1}<0$$
Informally,
$$-2+(1+(<-1)(>1))(>1)\rightarrow-2+(1+(<-1))(>1)\rightarrow-2+(<0)(>1)\rightarrow-2+(<0)<0$$